# Convert CSV Data Stream into Pandas DataFrame (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have a CSV data stream/object called `jobresults`:

```
"number","person1","person2","type"
1234,"Michael Scott","Pam Beasley",false
2345,"Michael Scott","Jim Halpert",true
3456,"Jim Halpert","Dwight Schrute",false
```

How do I convert this object (it is NOT written out to a file) to a Pandas DataFrame?

I tried:

```
df = pd.read_csv(jobresults)
```

...to no avail. I believe `read_csv` requires an actual file pulled from the OS.

Any insight will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [**`io.StringIO`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO)

As [**stated here**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/io.html)

For Python 3 use

```
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(jobresults))
```

For Python 2 use

```
from StringIO import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(jobresults))
```

---

Considering your object is a [**splunklib.binding.ResponseReader**](http://docs.splunk.com/DocumentationStatic/PythonSDK/1.0/binding.html) You may need to use the `read()` method...

Try this:

```
from StringIO import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(jobresults.read()))
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: 
  `File "<ipython-input-39-64e491fd9bb9>", line 69, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(jobresults))

TypeError: initial_value must be unicode or None, not ResponseReader` I'm using Python 2.7 if that matters.

Comment: What is `type(jobresults)`?

Comment: `splunklib.binding.ResponseReader` - it is a feed from a Splunk query

Comment: Perfect - thank you very much. Apologies for the simple question.